# Get path in faces-config

Tags: jsf

i want to get the path in faces-config file in JSF to embedded into xhtml page. In faces-config:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>left</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/Template/LeftPage.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

In xhtml, i want to get it in ui tag `<ui:include src="??????" />`, please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think faces-config is use for *declaring managed bean* and *navigation pages*.
    use like this ,

```
 <f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"/>
 <head>
 </head>
    <body  >
    <h:form >
    <div id="messagediv">
        <rich:messages globalOnly="true" style="color:red;font-size:12px;weight:bold;"/>
    </div>
        <div align="center">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="1160">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            ***<ui:include src="/include/header1.xhtml" />***
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div style="background:white;padding: 20px 20px 20px 30px;height:#{contentHeight}px;">
                                <ui:insert name="content"/>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC! I have trouble in using path. If this is index page, dose not in any folder, which i would use `<ui:include src="/include/header1.xhtml" />` but i'm stay a page in folder named `Emp`, so how can i do that? I don't know sometime i must append `/faces/` to prefix so page may understand sometime i don't need it.